# Create a .class file from Java file which is present inside a jar without unpacking the jar

Tags: java, jar, compilation, cmd

I have opened a jar file in a Winzip, there is a Java file that need some modification, modified it inside jar. Now the Java file's .class is needed. How can I generate class file from a Java File which is inside the Jar. Do let me know any command line available. I cannot unpack the jar as there are some class files inside that is not open source. Overall I want to add a line of code to java file and replace  class file with update version of java file.

Comment: How did you modify the Java file inside the Jar? If it was src what will compiling it and placing it in the Jar do? I'm confused; but I think you can compile java source with that jar file in the classpath and then replace the old version of the class file with the newly compiled class file in the jar.

Comment: I modified Java file inside jar by opening it in a winzip, you  can do that. Now how to generate the class file of that modified Java file. @ElliottFrisch Any Idea...

Comment: I already told you. Compile it with `javac -cp myjar.jar thefile.java` and then replace the version of the `.class` in the jar with the new `.class`

Comment: I did that from cmd it saying TaiMessenger.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
hpackage com.hds.tai;

Comment: You have to compile the java file into a class file first. You cannot compile a java file inside a jar file.

Comment: Dats what Elliot I am unable to get a class file out of java file which is inside jar...  So is there not any way we can compile a java file inside a  jar.

Comment: [javac technotes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) *You should arrange source files in a directory tree that reflects their package tree. For example, if you keep all your source files in C:\workspace, the source code for com.mysoft.mypack.MyClass should be in C:\workspace\com\mysoft\mypack\MyClass.java.* Why did you think the java compiler would compile from a zip (jar) file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67180/discussion-between-rohan-k-and-elliott-frisch).